# Count number of lines in a wrapping NSTextField having attributed strings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

How do I get the number of lines in an `NSTextField` which may or may not contain `NSAttributedStrings`?

Comment: Does this help: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html ?

Comment: @koen:  I already checked that, it is too old, archived, API has changed, however they are using TextView I have NSTextField.

Comment: Agreed it's a bit dated, but the idea to use `NSLayoutManager` and friends seems a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringValue` to get the string, then count the number of `newline` characters. For that see [this article from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html)

To handle the case where the string is attributed, you should try `attributedStringValue` and get the string from there :

```
attributedString.string
```

Comment: As I say "Wrapping nstextfield", that means without \n or \r the text will come to the next line.

Comment: That's another challenge... Sorry for misunderstanding you.

Comment: Another challenge yes! This is not a perfect solution but may help a bit. See how far you can get with attributed string's ```boundingRectWithSize:options:context:``` message.